# black screen while running ios and working android

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase-analytics

Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           48.5s
Installing and launching...
(lldb) 2023-05-15 22:57:48.735968+0300 Runner[2172:719196]  - [I-ACS036001] Analytics screen reporting is disabled. UIViewController transitions will not be logged.
`GrMtlCommandBuffer: WARNING: Creating MTLCommandBuffer while in background.`
`GrMtlCommandBuffer: WARNING: Creating MTLCommandBuffer while in background.`
`<SKPaymentQueue: 0x283f37bd0>: No observers found that respond to`

``` "paymentQueue:shouldAddStorePayment:forProduct:", will not check for purchase intents`` ```  [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023007] Analytics v.10.7.0 started  [FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following `

application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
 `[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS025036] App Delegate Proxy is disabled`
 `[FirebaseAnalytics][I-ACS023013] Analytics collection disabled`